# align texts or images in Bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use Bootstrap 3.3.4 and I want to know which way is better to align texts or items in carousel.

[image]

here is a exemple from a slider. How can I align text like this and stay at any screen resolution at the same place. I use `top: x, right: x` but every time when I resize the window, text climb above and not stay at middle anymore.

CSS for align

```
.carousel-caption {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15%;
  bottom: 40%;
  left: 15%;
  z-index: 10;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}
```

Just basic bootstrap slider. But If I use bottom 40% for exemple to rise text at middle of the page works. But if I use smaller displays the text rise and stay almost on top.

In this [exemple](http://themeforest.net/item/eco-nature-environment-ecology-html5-template/full_screen_preview/11656881) text stay fixed on every device.

Comment: What CSS styles have you tried?

Comment: @hope - its very important that you specify what all things you have tried so far. I suggest - you also share the code through JSFIDDLE.net.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="display-table">
        <div class="display-cell">
           <h1>Title in here</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
.wrap {
    width:            100%;
    height:           400px;
}
.display-table {
    width:            100%;
    height:           100%;
    display:          table;
}
.display-cell {
    width:            100%;
    height:           100%;
    display:          table-cell;
    vertical-align:   middle;
}
</style>
```

This allows fixed vertical alignment and should work cross browser. Just note the fixed height applied to .wrap must be present for the children to inherit 100% height!

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I know that method. But dosen't work in bootstrap slider... idk why. I use position relative anything. Dosen't work. The text are behind the slider image...

Answer (score 0):

**Hope**, Try this demo that centers text vertically in the Bootstrap carousel.

Here is the **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yg5r07g1/)**.

All I do here is give the `div` a height that contains the text and then position it with this css...

```
.vcenter {
    position: absolute;
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    top:50%;
    bottom:50%;
    margin-top: -50px; 
    margin-bottom: -50px;
}
```